# How to convert length of time to numeric in R?

Tags: r, strptime, posixlt

I have a data frame with the amount of time it takes to do a lap and I'm trying to separate that into individual data frames for each driver.

These time values look like this, being in minutes:seconds.milliseconds, except for the first lap which has a Colon in between seconds and milliseconds.

```
13:14:50 1:28.322 1:24.561 1:23.973 1:23.733 1:24.752
```

I'd like to have these in a separate data frame in a seconds format like this.

```
794.500 88.322 84.561 83.973 83.733 84.752
```

When I convert this to a numeric it gives the following values.

```
214 201 174 150 133 183
```

And when I use `strptime` or `POSIXlt` it gives me huge values which are also wrong, even when I use the format codes. However, I subtracted 2 values to find that the time difference was correct, and through that I found that were all off by `1609164020`. Also, these values ignore the decimal values which I need.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I think your interpretation of the first entry is wrong.  That looks much more like a time than a duration. Does it ever have 3 digits for the milliseconds?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the data that you have. See here on [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Also do you really need the output in separate dataframes? So each dataframe would have only 1 value in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **POSIXlt** in conjunction with a conversion to seconds.

First, add a date to your first time element:

```
ds <- c("13:14:50", "1:28.322", "1:24.561", "1:23.973", "1:23.733", "1:24.752")
ds[1] <- paste( Sys.Date(), ds[1] )
#[1] "2020-12-29 13:14:50" "1:28.322"            "1:24.561"           
#[4] "1:23.973"            "1:23.733"            "1:24.752"
```

Create a function to convert the subsequent **minutes:seconds.milliseconds** to **seconds.milliseconds**:

```
to_sec <- function(x){ as.numeric(sub( ":.*","", x )) * 60 +
  as.numeric( sub( ".*:","", x ) ) }
```

Convert the vector to dates that enable calculation of time differences:

```
ds[2:6] <- to_sec(ds[2:6])
ds[2:6] <- cumsum(ds[2:6])

dv <- c( as.POSIXlt(ds[1]), as.POSIXlt(ds[1]) + as.numeric(ds[2:6]) )
# [1] "2020-12-29 13:14:50 CET" "2020-12-29 13:16:18 CET"
# [3] "2020-12-29 13:17:42 CET" "2020-12-29 13:19:06 CET"
# [5] "2020-12-29 13:20:30 CET" "2020-12-29 13:21:55 CET"

dv[6] - dv[1]
# Time difference of 7.089017 mins
```